Is there an NP-hard problem that becomes polynomial when the inputs are at most $2^n$?
Let Q be a computational problem that accepts as input some $n$ non-negative integers. Is it possible (assuming $P\neq NP$) that Q is NP-hard in general, but can be solved in polynomial time when restricted to inputs in the range $[0,2^n]$?
If, instead of $2^n$, there was any function that is polynomial in $n$, then the answer would be "yes", as there are many NP-hard problems that can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time, such as the knapsack problem.
For some specific NP-hard problems, the question is "no". For example, it is easy to prove that the Partition problem is NP-hard even when restricted to inputs in $[0,2^n]$, as we can always add zeros without changing the outcome, such that $n$ becomes equal to $\log_2$ of the largest integer in the input. But I am not sure if this trick works for other problems.
Is it possible in general?

Yes, absolutely.  Let $f:\{0,1\}^*\to \{0,1\}$ be the function corresponding to 3-SAT, i.e., if $x \in \{0,1\}^*$, we interpret $x$ as a representation of a 3-CNF formula, then $f(x)=1$ if this formula is satisfiable or 0 otherwise.  Computing $f$ is NP-hard.  Of course there is a bijection between $\{0,1\}^*$ and $\mathbb{N}$, so we can think of $f$ as a function with signature $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$.  Now define the function $g$ by
$$g(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \begin{cases}
f(x_1) &\text{if $n=1$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Let $Q$ be the problem to compute $g$.  Then this problem is NP-hard, since 3-SAT is.  Yet if you restrict all input integers to be in the range $[0,2^n-1]$, $g$ can be computed in polynomial time, by hardcoding the correct value of $g(0)$ and $g(1)$ and then returning 0 for all other inputs.

Let X be any NP-complete problem, and P any polynomial time decision problem, both taking n integers as input. Define X’ = P if all n numbers are <= 2^n, and as X’ = X if any number is greater than 2^n.
We can check in polynomial time that all numbers are 2^n, and get the solution for these instances in further polynomial time.
